# pymongo bulkwrite time consistently increasing

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bulkupdate

I am working on a project where I need to process huge number of data.

As a part of processing I am going through following steps -

1. Read CSV line
2. Translate CSV row to dictionary
3. Bulk Upsert 1000 rows in MongoDB
4. Iterate till the end of CSV file

The logic is fairly simple and is working fine without issues for millions of records.

However, the [`bulk_write`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations) time is consistently increasing.

The first call takes 0.55 seconds and it starts increasing for next batches.

### Statistics

[image]

> EDIT - Adding Database Logs

Adding database logs to prove that the database time is consistently increasing (shown at the end of log line)

```
2019-03-29T10:55:43.726+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 4439, w: 4439 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 4438, W: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 4438 } } } protocol:op_query 531ms

2019-03-29T10:55:45.214+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12250, w: 12250 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 12250 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 12250 } } } protocol:op_query 1040ms

2019-03-29T10:55:47.041+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 20059, w: 20059 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 20059 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 20059 } } } protocol:op_query 1406ms

2019-03-29T10:55:49.390+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 27870, w: 27870 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 27870 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 27870 } } } protocol:op_query 1733ms

2019-03-29T10:55:52.099+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 35679, w: 35679 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 35679 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 35679 } } } protocol:op_query 2209ms

2019-03-29T10:55:55.046+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 43503, w: 43503 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 43503 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 43503 } } } protocol:op_query 2453ms

2019-03-29T10:55:58.724+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 51325, w: 51325 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 51325 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 51325 } } } protocol:op_query 3146ms

2019-03-29T10:56:02.565+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 59127, w: 59127 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 59127 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 59127 } } } protocol:op_query 3413ms

2019-03-29T10:56:06.820+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 66941, w: 66941 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 66941 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 66941 } } } protocol:op_query 3868ms

2019-03-29T10:56:11.890+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 74747, w: 74747 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 74747 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 74747 } } } protocol:op_query 4612ms

2019-03-29T10:56:17.461+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 82567, w: 82567 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 82567 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 82567 } } } protocol:op_query 5118ms

2019-03-29T10:56:23.417+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 90397, w: 90397 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 90397 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 90397 } } } protocol:op_query 5502ms

2019-03-29T10:56:30.232+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 98209, w: 98209 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 98209 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 98209 } } } protocol:op_query 6377ms

2019-03-29T10:56:37.326+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 106014, w: 106014 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 106014 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 106014 } } } protocol:op_query 6606ms

2019-03-29T10:56:44.692+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 113818, w: 113818 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 113818 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 113818 } } } protocol:op_query 6970ms

2019-03-29T10:56:53.036+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 121635, w: 121635 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 121635 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 121635 } } } protocol:op_query 7678ms

2019-03-29T10:57:01.974+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 129463, w: 129463 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 129463 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 129463 } } } protocol:op_query 8385ms

2019-03-29T10:57:10.969+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 137277, w: 137277 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 137277 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 137277 } } } protocol:op_query 8517ms

2019-03-29T10:57:20.760+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 145089, w: 145089 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 145089 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 145089 } } } protocol:op_query 9189ms

2019-03-29T10:57:30.568+0000 I COMMAND  [conn38] command test_db.$cmd command: update { update: "car_records", ordered: false, updates: 1000 } numYields:0 reslen:37964 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 152891, w: 152891 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { w: 152891 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { w: 152891 } } } protocol:op_query 9294ms
```

### Code

```
# save records in database
def insert_car_records(db, records, header):
    try:
        if db and header and records:
            a = datetime.datetime.now()
            coll = db.get_collection("car_records")
            db_cars = convert_csv_row(header, records)
            rq = []
            for car in db_cars:
                obj = { "$set": car }
                rq.append(UpdateOne({"uid": car["uid"]}, obj, upsert=True))
            bulkop = coll.bulk_write(rq, ordered=False)
            b = datetime.datetime.now()
            delta = b - a
            print("nInserted count - {}".format(bulkop.bulk_api_result["nInserted"]))
            print("nMatched count - {}".format(bulkop.bulk_api_result["nMatched"]))
            print("nModified count - {}".format(bulkop.bulk_api_result["nModified"]))
            print("nRemoved count - {}".format(bulkop.bulk_api_result["nRemoved"]))
            print("nUpserted count - {}".format(bulkop.bulk_api_result["nUpserted"]))
            print("time is seconds - {}".format(delta.total_seconds()))
    except BulkWriteError as bwe:
        print(bwe.details)
        raise
```

As shown, the above function gets called once 1000 CSV rows are processed.

The code to generate 1000 rows is simple as follows -

```
def init():
    quotechar = '"'
    paginated_rows = []
    page_size = 1000
    for line in request.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
        if len(paginated_rows) == page_size:
            insert_car_records(database, paginated_rows)
            paginated_rows = []
        #  prepare new row
        paginated_rows.append(generate_row(line, quotechar))
```

You can ignore syntax errors in the code as I have modified it before pasting it here

I am familiar with mongo and understand how bulk operations can boost performance.

However, I am new to python and I think I'm missing something here.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be expected. That's just the nature of "upserts" because you are **matching** a document to either update it or then insert where no match is found. It would be worse with no index on the field used in the predicate, but there also would be an effect even with an index, as the index itself needs to be *appended to* with every **upsert**. Those alone are just facts that would cause a progressively longer duration.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn for a quick reply. I do understand these concerns but I was not expecting the processing to be this slower. I have worked on a lot of NodeJs Apps with millions of rows of CSVs getting processed within minutes. I have used exactly the same approach here but the performance difference is massive. I mean 10 seconds for updating 1000 rows in 20th iteration just doesn't make any sense, isn't it?

Comment: But NodeJS is "asynchronous" where as your Python code is not. Therein lies the "apples and oranges". You can write "asynchronous" code in python, it's just that you have not done that.

Comment: Well that is one way to solve this problem. I will try it out. However, if we look at the database logs, database itself is taking incremental time and the rate at which its increasing is huge. Even if I am doing synchronous operations, I wasn't expecting MongoDb to get this slower. Anyway, I will try the `indexing` and `async` solutions and come back with the results. Thanks

Comment: Adding index to the collection made a huge difference for me. Without it each bulkWrite was taking 5 seconds more than the previous one. With indexing everything each bulkWrite takes around 0.2 sec. Huge difference.